# How to get some characters after a specific string and use it as file name

Tags: python, multilinestring

I have a multiline string, which needs to be pasted and saved into a .txt file. I need also use some characters from the string as file name.

Here is an input example:

```
ABCD 0000/20/02
Q) abc/yxz/IV/A /000/999
A) XYZ B) 2008311600 C) 2009301559
E) texttexttext
texttext
```

File name should contain 6 numbers after `B)` : `200831` and the extension `txt`.

That's what I have:

```
print ('Paste new NOTAM starting with AXXXX/20: ')    ##paste notam
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break

file_name= line[line.find("B) ")[6]:]
print (file_name)

with open(input(file_name + '.txt', "w+")) as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are asking, but `open(input(file_name ...))` should just be `open(file_name ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regex` to find out file name:

```
import re

string = '''ABCD 0000/20/02<br />
Q) abc/yxz/IV/A /000/999<br />
A) XYZ B) 2008311600 C) 2009301559<br />
E) texttexttext<br />
texttext<br />'''

filename = re.findall('B\) (\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)', string)[0]

with open(f'{filename}.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(string)
```

Output file is `2008311.txt`

Comment: yes, thanks that is what i meant. 
but how can I use the pasted at same beginning multiline string (input), without defining it once again?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you provide step-by-step use case?

Answer (score 0):

so here i'm pasting my input, which is multiline string:

```
print ('Paste new NOTAM starting with AXXXX/20: ')    ##paste notam
lines = []
while True:
        line = input()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
```

Now i need to simply use those 6 characters from already pasted input in file name

Answer (score 0):

In your code, all `lines` need to be checked, not only one `line`, so:

```
for line in lines:
    if "B)" in line:
        file_name = line[line.find("B) ")[6]:]
        print (file_name)
```

Then, it is not really clear from your question whether you keep all multiline strings in memory or in separate files. Either way, you can write a function so that you can use it in different scenarios:

```py
def parse_lines(lines):

    for line in lines:
        if "B)" in line:
            file_name = line[line.find("B) ")[6]:]
            print (file_name)

    with open(file_name + '.txt', "w+") as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)
            f.write('\n')
```

So your code will look like this:

```py
print ('Paste new NOTAM starting with AXXXX/20: ')    ##paste notam

lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break

parse_lines(lines):
```

Or if you plan to parse batch files with this method:

```py
import sys

with open(sys.argv[0], 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    parse_lines(lines)
```